# Save a pivottablejs figure to file

Tags: javascript, python, pandas, pivot-table, jupyter-notebook

I have started using the package `pivottablejs` to manipulate and visualize pivot tables in python.

```
from pivottablejs import pivot_ui
pivot_ui(df)  # where df is a pandas dataframe
```

will produce an interactive pivot table/plot in a jupyter notebook.

Is there any pythonic way to save the figures produced by this package to (say) `png` from within the jupyter notebook? I am looking for something similar to the classic `plt.savefig('file.png')`. The front-end is essentially `javascript`, and I do not know how (or if it is possible) to access a javascript figure through python.

Comment: you can save the file using pickle.  Are you looking to snapshot the image on the screen instead though?

Comment: Ideally I would like the same result as plt.savefig('file.png')

Answer (score 4):

This is too long for a comment, so I'm adding it as an answer. `pivottablejs` creates images as svgs and they do not provide any download/export mechanism for the images. But what you can do is inject js into the cell and download the svg using that.

One simple way of doing this is using [svg-crowbar.js](https://nytimes.github.io/svg-crowbar/svg-crowbar.js). After you generate the chart using `pivot_ui` and the output is displayed on the screen, run the following in the next cell to download the svg.

```
In [10]: %%javascript
         var e = document.createElement('script'); e.setAttribute('src', 'https://nytimes.github.io/svg-crowbar/svg-crowbar.js'); e.setAttribute('class', 'svg-crowbar'); document.body.appendChild(e);
```

Note: This only works on chrome.

Comment: Thanks. This works (on chrome).  It seems to be the best solution at the moment, although it is not exactly what I had in mind

Comment: I understand, but maybe you can use matplotlib instead of pivottablejs. That way you can get a png that you can save.

Answer (score 2):

you can save it as html by specifying outfile_path

```
pivot_ui(df, outfile_path="yourpathname.html")
```

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't this save the whole page? I just need to save the figure.