# pivottablejs does not display any result in the jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-visualization, pivottable.js

pivottablejs does not display any result in the jupyter notebook. Clicking on the hyperlink(pop out), displays an empty page.

```
from pivottablejs import pivot_ui
from IPython.display import IFrame
from IPython.core.display import display

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv',encoding='utf-8')
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try: print pivot_ui(df)  ?

Comment: It prints `<IPython.lib.display.IFrame object at 0x000000A619800F28>`

Comment: maybe this post can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43758224/save-a-pivottablejs-figure-to-file

Comment: @Joe It creates a blank HMTL on saving it as given in the link

Comment: (I'm the author of this library) if you create an issue here https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/jupyter_pivottablejs/issues/new I'd be glad to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

See this solution (on https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable/issues/1269) that worked for me.

> Hi, I did not find a workaround to use pivottable on vscode. But, if
> you open the pivottablejs.html that is generated into your folder in a
> web browser, you're able to use it normally.

This is my code that worked. First, I defined my path and saved an HTML file. Then I opened this html file in chrome, and it worked well.

```
#!pip install pivottablejs
from pivottablejs import pivot_ui
pivot_ui(df, outfile_path=r"D:\XXXXXX\pivot.html")
```